# SQL to display pivoted data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:
[image]

and i want the following output displayed:

[image]

the above is basically the (quan*cst) for each day. Now I can acieve this by the following sql:

```
   select  t1.pid, isnull(b.m1,0) as day1sale, isnull(a.m2,0) as day2sale
 from dbo.test1 t1
 left join(select pid, sum(quan*cst) m1
 from dbo.test1  where date='2017-05-01' group by pid) b on b.pid=t1.pid 
 left join (select pid, sum(quan*cst) m2
 from dbo.test1  where date='2017-05-02' group by pid) a on a.pid=t1.pid 
 group by t1.pid,m2 ,m1
 order by t1.pid
```

But i was wondering if there is a simpler way to do it without actually having to hard code the dates?

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Look into using the `PIVOT` operator.  Not necessarily simpler, but maybe less code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a self join to get a list of distinct dates, the result set can be pivoted and the desired aggregates applied to each PID.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_EXAMPLE
(
[DATE] DATE,
[ID] INT,
[PID] INT,
[QUAN] INT,
[CST] INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/01/2017','1','1','2','3')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/01/2017','2','2','6','2')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/01/2017','3','3','5','1')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/01/2017','4','1','1','3')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/02/2017','5','3','3','1')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/02/2017','6','4','4','7')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/02/2017','7','1','7','3')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/02/2017','8','5','2','8')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/02/2017','9','6','5','6')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_EXAMPLE VALUES('05/02/2017','10','2','8','2')


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY [DATE]) AS ID,*
INTO #TEMP_DYNAMIC_DATES
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #TEMP_EXAMPLE ) AS X

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_DYNAMIC_DATES

SELECT PID,ISNULL(DAY1SALE,0) AS DAY1SALE,ISNULL(DAY2SALE,0) AS DAY2SALE FROM (
SELECT PID,SUM([QUAN] * [CST]) AS X, INDIC FROM (
SELECT A.*,
CASE WHEN B.ID = 1 THEN 'DAY1SALE'
     WHEN B.ID = 2 THEN 'DAY2SALE'
     END AS INDIC 
     FROM #TEMP_EXAMPLE AS A 
JOIN #TEMP_DYNAMIC_DATES AS B
ON A.DATE = B.DATE
) AS X
GROUP BY PID,INDIC) AS O
PIVOT(SUM(X) FOR INDIC IN([DAY1SALE],[DAY2SALE])) AS PT
```

[image]